# NDK Library Not Found

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

I'm getting the following error;

```
E/AndroidRuntime(446): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library XYZ not found
```

but I have library XYZ in my project. The folder struct is:

```
-ProjectFolder
--obj
---local
----armeabi
-----objs
------libXYZ.so
------libstdc++.a
------XYZ
-------folderA
--------fileX.o
--------fileX.o.d
--jni
---Android.mk
---folderA
----fileX.cpp
----fileX.h
```

Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a x86
LOCAL_MODULE := XYZ
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := folderA/fileX.cpp
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

C++ compile output:

```
Compile++ thumb  : XYZ <= fileX.cpp
In file included from jni/folderA/fileX.h:1:0,
                 from jni/folderA/fileX.cpp:1:
/Applications/android-ndk-r8b/platforms/android-5/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:592:13: note: the mangling of 'va_list' has changed in GCC 4.4
StaticLibrary  : libstdc++.a
SharedLibrary  : libXYZ.so
Install        : libXYZ.so => libs/armeabi/libXYZ.so
```

I don't understand why the error says "Library XYZ not found", when the library is in the correct place.

Comment: No, it does not appear to be in the right place.  Please see the NDK docs.  Also open your apk as a zip file and look for the native libraries inside.  Finally use run-as on the device (or an emulator or rooted device) to view the installed directory of the application and verify that a matching-ABI version of the .so is being unpacked from the .apk.

Comment: @ChrisStratton on apk is normal /lib/armeabi/libXYZ.so

Comment: That's a good sign.  Next question is if it gets unpacked to the lib/ directory of the project's install directory on the device.

Comment: @ChrisStratton yes, on /data/data/<my package>/lib has the libXYZ.so

Comment: What is your System.loadLibrary() line in your java source?

Comment: @ChrisStratton thanks!!! you found!! I  was calling the wrong method, System.load() instead System.loadLibrary() ... very silly mistake.

Comment: Yes, System.load() is for when you want to explicitly specify the file (and path) to load, rather than let the system find and load a file matching the requested library name