# Library not found (but found in another activity) using OpenCV and Android NDK

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, android-ndk, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have went through a myriad of resources (including, but not limited to, [OpenCV4Android's Google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-opencv/LIixgr-iYSs/cEZWqxp5O3QJ), StackOverflow and [OpenCV's answers](http://answers.opencv.org/question/2658/static-initialization-problem/) page trying to resolve this, reaching a point where suggestions become redundant. The problem may be more or less similar to a previous (yet to be resolved) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588578/opencv-using-android-ndk-could-not-be-resolved-error) of mine, but a different situation and thus perhaps a different source of error.

I have added an Android Activity to a package containing a successfully-running app (OpenCV's tutorial 3 sample demonstrating ndk use). The activity uses OpenCV's java API, but there is a call to `System.loadLibrary("nativefile");` where `nativefile` represents a native library. The block where the `loadLibrary` is called is mentioned below; it is in the `onManagerConnected()` method. At the `loadLibrary` line, Logcat emits:

```
02-17 19:27:39.239: E/AndroidRuntime(10872): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-17 19:27:39.239: E/AndroidRuntime(10872): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library nativefile not found
02-17 19:27:39.239: E/AndroidRuntime(10872):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:461)
02-17 19:27:39.239: E/AndroidRuntime(10872):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:557)
```

Such error indeed did occur multiple times in other questions; and I have tried the suggestions I came across. However, there is a noteworthy observation to this problem; the app that successfully runs (the OpenCV sample) calls the same library through `System.loadLibrary("nativefile");`.

The code is rather long and thus not helpful to place in the question. However below summarises what I presume are key elements regarding the problem, it also summarises some of the previous answers related to the matter.

- The .cpp file called has the correct method name, where I verify that it includes the package name and the class name, as well as the method name, in a pattern similar to: `Java_packageNameSeperatedWithUnderScores_callingClassName_methodName`. Morever; the code is surrounded within an `extern "C"` block, as with other OpenCV sample cpp files for native development.
- The Android manifest is updated to learn that it launches the activity in question.
- Below is the `Android.mk` file:

  `LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
  include $(CLEAR_VARS)

  include ../../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
  LOCAL_MODULE    := nativefile

  LOCAL_SRC_FILES := nativefile.cpp

  LOCAL_LDLIBS +=  -llog -ldl

  include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)`
- Below is the `Application.mk` file

  `APP_STL := gnustl_static

  APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions

  APP_ABI := all`
- I have tried replacing `all` in the `APP_ABI` line with `armeabi` and also again tried with `armeabi-v7a`, no different results however.
- I've also verified, as suggested in a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385265/ndk-library-not-found), that the apk (after being extracted) contains the needed `.so` file in `lib` folder under the various architecture type folders.
- Below is the `BaseLoaderCallBack` instantiation block, not much unlike that in the OpenCV sample, however I do not call the OpenCV camera, since the app performs image processing on images read from the SD card.

  ```
   BaseLoaderCallback loader = new BaseLoaderCallback(this){
   public void onManagerConnected(int status){  
      switch(status){     
          case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:{ 
               System.loadLibrary("nativefile"); break; }  
          default:{  
               super.onManagerConnected(status); break; }  
      } } };
  ```
- Unlike OpenCV's sample however, in the Activity in question the line `loader.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);` is added to the `onCreate()` method, since the method `onManagerConnected` didn't seem to be called otherwise.
- Before every OpenCV block of statements, the condition `if (OpenCVLoader.initDebug())` is checked. I've also tried the [recommended](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/android/service/doc/JavaHelper.html)  `OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_3, this, loader)` conditional check, but still no different results.
- Also, the ndk-build runs successfully building the `.so` files for the native library `nativefile`.

Given that the other activity, within the same package, load the library and utilises it finely (of course after amending the manifest file and cpp method name accordingly), I presume the project properties are correct (such as adding OpenCV library, and necessary environment paths, etc).

I reviewed the OpenCV sample multiple times and followed the same practice with slight variances, as detailed above.

Any ideas what could be the source of the problem?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Open adb shell and run
 `ls -l /data/data/your.package.name/lib`